# Are aliased functions optimized in Erlang

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, erlang

Say i have a function that is exported from a module, but the modules uses the function many times.

So i wrote an alias, because i'm lazy when i code.

```
-export([get_toolkit/0]).

get_toolkit() -> 
    ... code ... code ... 
    ... code ... code ... 
    ... code ... code ... 
    {ok, Thing}.

tk() -> get_toolkit().
```

Does the compiler optimizes aliases ?

Thanks

Comment: If your code is being slowed down because of extra function calls, I'd argue that the rest of your code is already optimized to its fullest. In short, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't know, i did not measure the execution time of my code, this is more about knowledge and best practices :)

Comment: speaking of best practices I think that you should use the full name (clarity). If you find that it saves you a lot of time to use the shortcut, you can always automatically replace it in the end.

Comment: I agree with thanosQR here. Go for *readability* of the code first and then attack speed if it is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it will cost you one indirection. I say this because I took this code

```
-module(testit).
-export([get_toolkit/0, long/0, short/0]).

get_toolkit() -> 
    _ = lists:seq(1,100),
    {ok, thing}.

tk() -> 
   get_toolkit().

long() ->
    get_toolkit(),
    {ok, thing2}.

short() ->
    tk(),
    {ok, thing3}.
```

and generated the ASM via erlc -S testit.erl which gave me

```
SNIP

{function, tk, 0, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"testit.erl",8}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,testit},{atom,tk},0}.
  {label,4}.
    {call_only,0,{f,2}}.


{function, long, 0, 6}.
  {label,5}.
    {line,[{location,"testit.erl",11}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,testit},{atom,long},0}.
  {label,6}.
    {allocate,0,0}.
    {line,[{location,"testit.erl",12}]}.
    {call,0,{f,2}}.
    {move,{literal,{ok,thing2}},{x,0}}.
    {deallocate,0}.
    return.


{function, short, 0, 8}.
  {label,7}.
    {line,[{location,"testit.erl",15}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,testit},{atom,short},0}.
  {label,8}.
    {allocate,0,0}.
    {line,[{location,"testit.erl",16}]}.
    {call,0,{f,4}}.
    {move,{literal,{ok,thing3}},{x,0}}.
    {deallocate,0}.
    return.
```

- The first function listed in the snip-it is the "short-hand" function, tk/0.
- the second is the long function which calls get_toolkit/0,
- the third is the short function which uses the tk/0 short-hand

the ASM shows that the last function (the one that uses tk/0 ) calls tk/0 ({call, 0, {f, 4}}) which in turn calls get_toolkit/0 ({call, 0, {f,2}}). The function which uses get_toolkit/0 directly calls get_toolkit/0 directly ({call, 0, {f,2}}).

So, I think that there is no optimization applied.

Also, I did some time-tests which seemed to support this hypothesis ;)

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration :) I'll use a macro and look at the ASM

Comment: @Soup d'Campbells advice of using a macro of -define(tk, get_toolkit()). is probably the best way to do what you want to do

Answer (score 3):

(Unable to comment so have to include this in an additional answer...)

As an alternative you can tell the compiler to inline the function by adding:

```
-compile({inline,[tk/0]}).
```

then this

```
{function, get_toolkit, 0, 2}.
...
{function, tk, 0, 4}...
    {call_only,0,{f,2}}.
...
{function, short, 0, 8}...
    {call,0,{f,4}}.
...
```

will become

```
{function, get_toolkit, 0, 2}.
...
{function, short, 0, 6}...
    {call,0,{f,2}}.
```

which completely eliminates the `tk/0` function as it wasn't exported and the inlined code directly calls `get_toolkit`.

This is documented in http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html, section **Inlining**.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by optimized. Generally speaking, the compiler will optimize calls where it knows the module and function names at run-time, especially if the function is in the same module, so I'm inclined to say yes.

Comment: I mean : "calling tk() instead of get_toolkit() doesn't cost more CPU/RAM/..." :)

Comment: It will probably cost a cycle or two more to evaluate because of the secondary function. Use a compiler definition if you want to avoid that: `-define(tk, get_toolkit()).`

Comment: Ok, that's what i will do for now, seems simple.